# How to suppress firewall warning when a (signed) networked app runs (from Xcode)

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, firewall, xcode4.6

The `Code Signing Identity` in Xcode uses my `iPhone Developer` certificate.

[image: Code Signing Identity in Xcode]
Alas, I still *must* click `Allow` each time I try to test the `.app` in iOS Simulator. "It's just a click", but it gets old after a while.

[image: Firewall warning]

**Can this warning be suppressed? If so, how?**

---

I've already tried **(1)** manually removing & adding the `.app` in Mountain Lion's `Firewall Options`, **(2)** manually signing the `.app` from Terminal with `codesign`, **(3)** few other things I don't remember.

Regarding the **(2)**: signing the `.app` manually was "successful" ...

```
| 492 > codesign -vvv MyApp.app 
MyApp.app: valid on disk 
MyApp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

... but I guess it doesn't work because each `xcodebuild` replaces the old executable within the `.app`?

---

Vaguely related question: [Firewall impeding Bonjour network debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363479/firewall-impeding-bonjour-network-debugging)

Also related, later question: [How do I get the Mac OS X Firewall to permanently allow my iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845502/how-do-i-get-the-mac-os-x-firewall-to-permanently-allow-my-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

A solution using an automated mouse click:

1. Download [CLIclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/). (Thank you Carsten.)
2. Put it in a suitable location, say `/usr/local/bin`.
3. Get the `Allow` button's screen coordinates using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>. (In my example, these are x: 750, y: 600.)
4. Create a script with this content (the `w:` is the wait time in ms):

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/cliclick c:750,600 w:1500 m:+0,+0 c:.
   ```

   (I couldn't get `CLIclick` to work without "moving" it to the same location (the `m:+0,+0` part) and clicking again at the same spot (`c:.`).)
5. Open Xcode's `Preferences / Behaviors` and add the above script.
   [image]
6. Enjoy!

Of course, *the* solution of disabling the warning in the first place is still welcome.